# TensorFlow and Keras // 2 dimensional input /1st day beginner

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

It is my first day with tf and keras. I had a quick tutorial which worked fine, but left me with a lot of questions.
Can someone show me how to get two data inputs instead of one?

```py
import keras
import numpy as np

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')


xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], dtype=int) # input data 1
ys = np.array([8,11,14,17,20,23,26], dtype=int)

# formel is : 3*x+5

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500)

print(model.predict([10.0]))
```

Comment: You may want to edit your question title to let say that it's about TensorFlow and Keras, which may help you get the attention of people with relevant expertise and knowledge.

Comment: thanks mate...good idea :)

Comment: Add the data snippet of the multiple features input for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

add a few hidden layers for feature detection.  If you want multiple features then you will need to change the shape of X and the input shape

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], dtype=int).tolist() 
#ys = np.array([8,11,14,17,20,23,26], dtype=int)
ys=list(map(lambda x: 3*x+5,xs.tolist()))
plt.plot(xs,ys)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)
model=Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='main_input'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='tanh')) 
model.add(Dense(100, activation='tanh')) 
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh')) 
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train,  epochs=1000, verbose=0)

predictionResults=model.predict(X_test)

index=0
results=predictionResults.flatten()
for value in X_test:
    plt.scatter(value,results[index])
    index+=1
plt.plot(X,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Golden's answer, here is an example of adding another feature "x".  You should just mess around with the layers and sizes.

```py
import keras
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], dtype=int) # input data 1
x = np.array([3,5,7,9,11,13,15], dtype=int) # input data 2

ys = np.array([3,10,21,36,55,78,105], dtype=int)

# formel is : xs * x

input_data = np.array([[xs],[x]]).T

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=input_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='tanh'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='tanh'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(input_data, ys, epochs=500)

print(model(np.array([[10, 21]])).numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. it seems to work, but the last line causes error message: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 2), found shape=(1, 2)

Comment: @clalaagahan add an extra `[]` around the input data then.  It is expecting an extra dimension.

Comment: @blackdrump :) yeah.. finaly it works.  but now i have the next question. with one input the result is pretty close to what it should be. here i have 44.002583 for 8 and 17...?

Comment: @clalaagahan print out `print(model(input_data).numpy())` to see how close the values you trained on are to the predicted values.  If the prediction is not close, you could have to add more layers, change hyperparameters, increase the epoch's, or even add more training data

Comment: @blackdrump  thanks for the moment.. i am going to play around with that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

see https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/ for how to create a simple feedforward neural network with 10 inputs

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(10,), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))

This network is a simple feedforward neural without with 10 inputs, a first hidden layer with 8 nodes, a second hidden layer with 4 nodes, and a final output layer used for regression.

Keras allows you to create multiple sequential networks with inputs and concatenate them into a dense layer with one or more outputs
```